# Need help to find PID in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I am new to writing code. For getting process id I got the below code, but I am not able to understand what exactly the below command is doing, could you please anyone explain it.

```
for PID in `ps -u ${instuser} -o pid,args |
grep "\-classpath :$path" | grep -v grep | sed 's/^ *//g' | cut -f1 -d' '`
```

especially I am unable to understand why they used pid,args and sed command.

Could you please help me out ehat exactly it is?

Comment: The easiest is usually to try out the commands in the pipeline one by one. Meaning, first `ps ...`, then `ps ... | grep ...`, then `ps ... | grep ... | grep ...`. If any of those outputs is large, add `| less` at the end.

Comment: There is also `man ps` to explain `-o`.

Comment: Thank you so much for help, now i am clear with that command

Answer (score 1):

The `-o` option with ps command controls how the output is displayed as the manual says:

> -o
>  format  User-defined format.  format is a single argument in the form of a blank-separated or comma-separated list, which offers a way
>   to specify individual output columns.

The sed command

```
sed 's/^ *//g'
```

trims the white-spaces in the beginning of the output.

Answer (score 0):

The command is basically search all the process for a linux user. The variable ${instuser} represents the user.

-o option is the formatting option. The command used pid (processid) and args which is the full set of arguments used to launch the process.

The grep is used to filter and display only processes which have a "classpath" in the argument list.

grep -v grep is used to remove the process that runs the grep command.

sed is used to replace all the text with null. In this case, you are dropping all places which start with a space. ^ is used to identify the beginning and replace it with a null.

cut is being used to get the first field -f1 which is the process id.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help

Comment: how to mark it as helped, i didnt get any place to choose that option